# How to publish coverage report from gitlab CI artifacts folder?

Tags: python, gitlab, code-coverage, coverage.py

I am following the following tutorial to create code coverage report: [Publish code coverage report with GitLab Pages](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/11/03/publish-code-coverage-report-with-gitlab-pages/)

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks same as in the tutorial, except that I am doing it in python

```
image: ubuntu:18.04

variables:
    CODECOV_TOKEN: $CODECOV_TOKEN

stages:
    - coverage
    - deploy

coverage:
    stage: coverage
    before_script:
        - apt-get -y update
        - apt-get -y install curl python3-pip python3.7 zip
        - python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        - python3.7 -V
        - pip3.7 install -r requirements.txt

    script:
        - coverage run -m pytest
        - coverage report -m
        - coverage html
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - htmlcov/

pages:
    stage: deploy
    dependencies:
        - coverage
    script:
        - mv htmlcov/ public/
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - public/
```

When the `.yml` file is run, it creates an artifact named `public`
[image]
This folder contains `index.html` whose contents are

[image]

Now, I want to have 52% as a coverage badge in the repo. From the tutorial above, I would like to know which link should I use so that I can get the badge in the repo. In the tutorial, under **Using the code coverage report badge** section, they have a markdown source

```
[![Coverage report](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/badges/master/coverage.svg?job=coverage)](http://gitlab-org.gitlab.io/gitlab-ce/coverage-ruby)
```

I am a bit confused as to what these links are and thus would like to know what would this be for my project?

Comment: Coverage.py doesn't make badges.  I'm don't understand the gitlab URLs you are showing, or how those get the coverage total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project, go to **Settings** > **CI/CD** and expand the **General pipelines** section. You will find the necessary codes to add `pipeline` and `coverage` badges to your project. In this section, you can also specify the branch name so badges will show the status of that branch.

In case you stuck with the `coverage: unknown` badge, you may read my solution for the problem using this link:
[Gitlab coverage badge is always unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780206/gitlab-coverage-badge-always-unknow/67385444#67385444)

Answer (score 0):

Here in your

```
->> settings  
->> ci_cd  
->> General pipelines  
->> Test coverage parsing
```

it will scan you gitlab-ci logs to catch regex.

I guess!
However, I think it's the answer.