# Gitlab coverage badge always unknow

Tags: testing, gitlab-ci, code-coverage, badge

### The problem

I'm working on a Laravel package project and setting up a pipeline to test it (against php 7.3, 7.4 and 8.0) on merge request and publishing it to my package registry on main branch.

I'm trying to set up a badge for code coverage, but i can't make it work correctly since it is always dipslayng `unknown` percentage.

### What i've done

#### The pipeline

```yaml
stages:
  - dependancies
  - linting
  - test
  - publish

# Dependancies job
download dependancies:
  stage: dependancies
  # job stuff

# Linting jobs
phpcs:
  stage: linting
  # job stuff

# test jobs templates
.testing_template: &testing
  stage: test
  script:
    - php -dxdebug.mode=coverage vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-text --colors=never
  only:
    - merge_requests

# Testing jobs
php 8:
  image: mileschou/xdebug:8.0
  <<: *testing

php 7.4:
  image: mileschou/xdebug:7.4
  <<: *testing

php 7.3:
  image: mileschou/xdebug:7.3
  <<: *testing


#  Publish to package registry
publish:
  only:
    - master
    - tags
  # job stuff
```

So my pipeline works as follow:

- on the feature branch

  - download dependancies
  - lint code
  - test against php 7.3, 7.4 and 8.0
- on the main branch and on tags

  - publish the package to the packages registry

So the part executed on the merge request is as follow

[image]

Moreover, i can see code coverage for each test job in the pipeline job section

[image]

(I'm not sure why the tests results in different code coverage percentages since the codebase is the same, but is obviously related to the php version and probably specific optimizations done in code parsing.)

#### The badge

Since this is a Laravel package project i'm testing it with PhpUnit, so i used the given regex for the test coverage parsing setting (taken from the Gitlab [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-parsing)).

```regex
^\s*Lines:\s*\d+.\d+\%
```

I want a badge that show the code coverage status on the `master branch`, not on the feature branch, so i've created a coverage badge with the badge image url as follow (i added a reference to a specific test job, i.e. `php 7.4`)

```
https://gitlab.com/%{project_path}/badges/%{default_branch}/coverage.svg?job=php%207.4
```

but it keeps being displayed as

[image].

I've tought that Gitlab can't find the desired `php 7.4` job since it is not executed on the `master` branch but on a feature branch, so i tried replacing the `%{default_branch}` placeholder with the `%{commit_sha}` to reference a specific commit, but this doesn't work neither since (i suppose) it reference the merge commit (that triggered just the publish job) and not the one that triggered the entire pipeline.

### I'm stuck

I cannot figure out how to get the code coverage percentage for the `master` branch.

I don't want to execute testing again on the master branche since i've already tested the feature branch before merging it.

How can i do? Am I missing something?

Comment: You can use `+` instead of `%20` when merging job name words.  Example: `job=php+7.4`

Answer (score 16):

I was struggling with this too for a python project and found that the test coverage results is now deprecated (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#add-test-coverage-results-to-a-merge-request-deprecated)

The answer for me was to use the `coverage` keyword in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` with the required regex to extract the percentage from the job log

e.g.

```
test:
  stage: test
  extends: .python-reports
  script:
    - pipenv run pytest --cov --cov-report term-missing --cov-report xml:./coverage_out_report.xml --junitxml=./test_out_report.xml
  coverage: '/TOTAL.*\s+(\d+%)$/'
```

And my badge defined as

Link `https://gitlab.com/%{project_path}/-/commits/%{default_branch}`

Badge image URL `https://gitlab.com/%{project_path}/badges/%{default_branch}/coverage.svg`

Now I see the coverage as 100% on main (or master) and a nice green badge

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue in a different stack (**Java, Gradle, and Jacoco**). I've already solved the issue, and I will share what I've done. I hope my solution gives you some idea.

First, In your project, go to **Settings** > **CI/CD** and expand the **General pipelines** section. Fill the **Test coverage parsing** textbox with an appropriate regular expression based on the tool you are using. You can find the sample list of these regular expressions on this page:
[Test coverage parsing samples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#test-coverage-parsing)

Gitlab expects that the test runner tool will print the test coverage percent based on the given regular expression somewhere on the CI job's log. If the test runner engine doesn't print it to the console, you can do it manually. For instance:

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - gradle test jacocoTestReport --info
    # Print test coverage to console
    - cat build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%'
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/reports/jacoco/test/*
```

After making sure that the test coverage exists in the log, the badge will work perfectly.

[pipeline and coverage badge sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PE3SL.png)

Comment: I also found that if you don't output a coverage report in the `lcov` format and ensure it's committed back, the badges will continue to report out "unknown" for code-coverage.

Comment: Update 2022 - _"This feature is in its end-of-life process. It was deprecated in GitLab 14.8. The feature is removed in GitLab 15.0."_ From [Gitlab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/settings.html#add-test-coverage-results-using-project-settings-removed)

Comment: @Sagivb.g yes it's deprecated, they added a parameter in gitlab-ci.yaml - coverage